# Sieve gets stuck at the beginning

Tags: haskell, infinite, sieve

I wrote the following sieve:

```hs
isPrime :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Bool
isPrime n = all (\i -> n `mod` i /= 0)


sieve :: [Integer]
sieve = 2 : [i | i <- [3,5..], isPrime i sieve]
```

but I don't understand why it gets stuck after the first value. Running `take 10 sieve` results in `[2,` and nothing happens. It probably has something to do with infinite recursion. May the problem be that `sieve` is growing and at the same time it's used inside `isPrime`? For that reason I also tried modifying `isPrime` as follows, but without success:

```hs
isPrime :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Bool
isPrime n = all (\i -> n `mod` i /= 0) . takeWhile (<n)
```

**EDIT**: Surprisingly, @Jubobs's modification works:

```hs
isPrime :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Bool
isPrime n = all (\i -> n `mod` i /= 0) . takeWhile (\p -> p^2 <= n)
```

I cannot understand why this version of `takeWhile` works while the other does not. I see that with my previous version I tested many unnecessary divisors, but they were in a finite number nontheless.

---

The code should basically be equivalent to the following Python code:

```py
def is_prime(n, ps):
    for i in ps:
        if n % i == 0: return False
    return True


def sieve():
    yield 2
    n = 3
    ps = [2]
    while True:
        if is_prime(n, ps):
            yield n
            ps.append(n)
        n += 2
```

Comment: I haven't worked out the details, but you most likely get stuck in a nonterminating computation because you pass `sieve` (instead of only an appropriate prefix of `sieve`, i.e. `takeWhile (\p -> p^2 <= n) sieve`) to `isPrime`.

Comment: @Jubobs I tried adding your suggested modification and it works! Now I am really confused. Why should it work with `takeWhile (\p -> p^2 <= n)` and not with `takeWhile (<n)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cause an infinite recursion by applying `all` to the entire `sieve` and not just the values which you sieved so far. I.e. For the second element, `isPrime` tests *all* values in `sieve` instead of just `2`.

In your Python version, you wrote

```
is_prime(n, ps)
```

which only tests `n` against all numbers sieved so far. The Python equivalent of what you did in Haskell is basically

```
is_prime(n, sieve())
```

Now, using `takeWhile (<n)` won't help because that also requires calculating the sieve elements. Imagine what happens for the second element of `sieve` (which should be 3): it tests all values of the sieve for which `< 3` holds, but in order to test that you actually need to evaluate the sieve elements. So you still have an infinite recursion.

Comment: But why doesn't it work when I add the `takeWhile`? With that it should stop after a finite number of values.

Comment: I'm puzzled. I tried @Jubobs's suggested modification and it works. I cannot understand why his `takeWhile` works while mine does not.

Comment: Oh now it's clear, thanks! Using the other `takeWhile` works because it only uses already computed primes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the comprehension list in sieve won't end until it completes, never. To use take like that, sieve would have to return the elements one by one. For instance, `[1..]` shows `1, 2 ,3 ,4...` to infinity but your sieve only shows `[2`.

Or clearly not what I said